# Need help in SQL Server to list and count status of the animal

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm in need of a SQL Server query where I can count and group by status, the table looks like this

```
name    status
---------------
frog    1
frog    0
frog    0
rabbit  0
rabbit  1
rabbit  0
rabbit  0
```

The output would be something like this:

```
name   status0   status1
-------------------------
frog   2         1
rabbit 3         1
```

Thank you!

Comment: Google for "pivot query SQL"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use `PIVOT`

```
DECLARE @T TABLE(name VARCHAR(10),   status INT)
INSERT INTO @T
VALUES
('frog',  1 ),
('frog',  0 ),
('frog',  0 ),
('rabbit',  0 ),
('rabbit',  1 ),
('rabbit',  0 ),
('rabbit',  0 )

SELECT name, [0] status0, [1] status1 FROM @T
    PIVOT(COUNT(status) FOR status IN ([0],[1])) PVT
```

Result:

```
name       status0     status1
---------- ----------- -----------
frog       2           1
rabbit     3           1
```

Comment: PIVIT is great! but what if the status is not set, meaning there could be status2, status3 ... etc?

Comment: It only counts status 1 and 2. if you have other statuses, you should add those statuses too to the query. If you want to make it dynamically, you should convert this query dynamic sql. this link will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48308332/sql-pivot-with-dynamic-header/48308799#48308799

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Select name, 
       Count(Case When Status = 0 Then 1 Else Null End) AS Status0,
       Count(Case When Status = 1 Then 1 Else Null End) AS Status1
FROM TableName
Group By name
```

Key note here is that, `Count` aggregate function will ignore `NULL` values and will not count them, this is why we use `Null` in Case's `Else` part!